# Haskell - Join two functions with the same input

Tags: function, haskell

I have 2 different very simple functions with the same input-output structure (Both return a count(*) when avg of 3 notes is >= 4 (*function1*) and the other a count(*) when avg of 3 notes is < 4 (*function2*)), They both work properly in separate but now i need to join both into just one function with 2 outputs, I now maybe is a very easy question but i am only getting started with Haskell:

```
function1::[(String, Int,Int,Int)]->Int
function1 ((name,note1,note2,note3):xs) = 
    if (note1+note2+note3) `div` 3 >=4 then length xs else length xs

function2::[(String, Int,Int,Int)]->Int
function2 ((name,note1,note2,note3):xs) = 
    if (note1+note2+note3) `div` 3 <4 then length xs else length xs
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: edits must not invalidate existing answers. if you have new question to ask, do please post a new question. if it is related to this one, i.e. a followup, you can always provide a link back to this one for reference as a background.

Comment: when posting a question, "it isn't working for me" is not enough information. show the intended and the actual input and output, and error messages in full, if any. if you found one of the answers here useful enough to form a new, followup question, do mark that question as being useful, to signal that this current issue is resolved. each new problem, however small, requires a new post. _small steps_.

Comment: Both of these functions return `length xs` regardless. Its possible you want `Either`, which lets you indicate which case the value comes from. If you explain what you are trying to achieve it might help.

Comment: @PaulJohnson it looks like some placeholder code. that wasn't the question though. the question was how to combine two functions into one that would produce the two outputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use &&& from Control.Arrow.

```
combineFunctions f1 f2 = f1 &&& f2
```

Then use it like this :

```
combinedFunc = combineFunctions function1 function2
(res1,res2) = combinedFunc  sharedArg
```

Comment: is pointfree code really a good fit for someone taking their first steps in Haskell?

Answer (score 0):

You already use tuples `(name,note1,note2,note3)` in your input data, so you must be familiar with the concept.

The simplest way to produce two outputs simultaneously is to put the two into one tuple:

```
combinedFunction f1 f2 input = (out1, out2)
   where
   out1 = f1 input
   out2 = f2 input
```

It so happens that this can be written shorter as `combinedFunction f1 f2 = f1 &&& f2` and even `combinedFunction = (&&&)`, but that's less important for  now.

A more interesting way to produce two outputs simultaneously is to redefine what it means to produce an output:

```
combinedFunWith k f1 f2 input = k out1 out2
   where
   out1 = f1 input
   out2 = f2 input
```

Here instead of just returning them in a tuple, we pass them as arguments to some other user-specified function `k`. Let *it* decide what to do with the two outputs!

As can also be readily seen, our first version can be expressed with the second, as  `combinedFunction = combinedFunWith (,)`, so the second one seems to be more general (`(,)` is just a shorter way of writing a function `foo x y = (x,y)`, without giving it a name).